# Mongodb: Get top documents

Tags: database, mongodb, max, aggregation

I am unable to find an answer to a problem either on Google or SO.

I have a collection such as :

```
{ "_id" : "0", "timestamp" : 160000 }
{ "_id" : "00", "timestamp" : 160000 }
{ "_id" : "000", "timestamp" : 150000 }
```

And I want to get the top rows based on `timestamp`, not only the top one.

This for example:

```
{ "_id" : "0", "timestamp" : 160000 }
{ "_id" : "00", "timestamp" : 160000 }
```

The obvious solution would be to sort DESC and get the first n rows, but this doesn't actually do what is required, I would need to know the number of top elements etc.

I'd like to get the timestamp of the top row and then match all rows that have that timestamp, or perhaps something else?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make use of self lookup to perform lookup on the same collection after finding the max value.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$sort": {
      "timestamp": -1
    }
  },
  {
    "$limit": 1
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "collection",
      "localField": "timestamp",
      "foreignField": "timestamp",
      "as": "topTimeStamp"
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0,
      "result": "$topTimeStamp"
    }
  },
  
])
```

[Mongo Sample Execution](https://mongoplayground.net/p/vDZLJPegSz7)

Sort `timestamp` key in descending order to improve query performance.

If the number of documents in the collection will be lesser, I recommend you to replace `$sort` and `$limit` stages with `$group` stage and find the max value using `$max` accumulator.

Comment: Amazing thank you, I'll accept once I test it!

Comment: An index on `{timestamp:-1}` could make that initial sort/limit lightning fast.